# Implement a Game Center leaderboard (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I need help with developing Game Center!
I found this developer web page http://blog.lucaslouca.com/game-center-leaderboard-ios-7-app/#comment-3761 and need some help with it

Here are my questions!

Hi, my name is David! I have developed game, it is like flappy bird and I need to implement game center! I have MyScene.m and MyScene.h, so I understand steps up to 7, but don't know if I should add those three files to my game I am not experienced game developer and need some help. I have few questions: 1) Do I have to add thee three files to my own game in order for game center to work GameCenterManager.h GameCenterManager.m AppSpecificValues.h?  2) Where exactly I should put this code? " 
// Dummy Highscore
NSUInteger _highscore = 1234;

// Sumbit highScore
[_gameCenterManager reportScore: _highscore forLeaderboardID:@"1"]; "

in MyScene.m? if yes can I put it in -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size delegate:(id)delegate state:(GameState)state 
or in  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event (I  have created button for game center and called the method in touches began). 3) Where should I put this delegate method - GKGameCenterControllerDelegate (Step 9) in My Scene.m or in View Controller.m?
For general info: I have only one UIView Controller in my game which is view controller. the scenes are navigated by "switch" method, each scene is game state something, of example GameStateMainMenue or GameStatePlay and so on. Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Game Center in IOS 7 leaderboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967767/game-center-in-ios-7-leaderboard)

Comment: Ok Wyatt! I will try to implement your version and tell you how it goes

Comment: OK Wyatt, I created new objective C file name it GCHelper and added it to my file. Then I copied your GCHelper.h and GCHelper.m from  Game Center in IOS 7 leaderboard –  Wyatt Mufson and pasted them into my GCHelper.h and m but when I build and run player doesn't get authenticated! Do I need to do something additional like add a navigation View Controller?

Comment: I authenticate in the app delegate

Comment: What code do you put there?

Comment: Wyatt so you saying this two GCHelper.h and GChelper.m will not authenticate player? I need to put some code in app delegate in ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithAptions? And what code should I put there?

Comment: You need to call the authenticate method from gchelper inthe app delegate

Comment: I called the authenticate method like this [self authenticateLocalPlayer];      in                                   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions but got this error " No visible interface For AppDelegate declares "authenticateLocalUser" What did i do wrong

Comment: I added your [[GCHelper sharedGameKitHelper] authenticateLocalPlayer]; method to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in app delegate but I am getting 2 errors: 1st is ARCSemantic issue "No known class method for selector 'sharedGameKitHelper' and second error is ARC Semantic Issue no known instance method for selector 'authenticateLocalPlayer' What do I fix now?

Comment: You have to import GCHelper.h to app delegate...

Comment: This what I have in my AppDelegate.m #import "GCHelper.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h" but still have those two errors

Comment: And you are sure you copied in all of GCHelper.h from the other page?

Comment: May I suggest you guys continue this conversation at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This is how it looks my GCHelper.h. See it in answer 2 below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the necessary code for a leaderboard see here:
[Game Center in IOS 7 leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967767/game-center-in-ios-7-leaderboard)

To authenticate the user you need this code:

```
[[GCHelper sharedGameKitHelper] authenticateLocalPlayer];
```

Comment: This is ho my GCHelper looks: